# Deploying new node.js keystoneJS app on Digital Ocean

Tags: node.js, mongodb, deployment, digital-ocean, keystonejs

I am close to deploying my first node app (KeystoneJS) + mongoDb and I was thinking of using Digital Ocean. This would be the first node app I have deployed and first time using Digital Ocean. I've tried to find tutorials or guides from other people deploying an app built on keystone but have failed to uncover one. I would greatly appreciate it someone could share the steps they used to deploy a node app + keystone + mongo they built.

Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

It's quite simple yet nobody explains in detail.
I had to bang my head for a while and I got it all figured out.
I'm not a Linux specialist.

First, you set up a droplet with MEAN configuration.
That takes care of the MongoDB and the Node setup.

Then you'll have to make Mongo to run as process:

Mongo
Step 1: Remove lock file.
`sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock`

Step 2: Repair mongodb.
`mongod --repair`

Step 3: 
`sudo mongod --port 27017 --fork --logpath /var/log/mongodb.log`

Step 4: Check status of mongodb.
`mongo`

After that, once you moved your keystone project into your opt/mean folder, running node keystone in your terminal should do it.

You'll see something like:

```
KeystoneJS Started:<br/>
[your project name] is ready on port 3000
```

I highly recommend you start by running your project on your local machine first and move it after you're able to run it on localhost:3000.

Comment: You'll also need to install forever (npm), to make sure your node server runs all the time, after you close the terminal window.